# Prevent copy and paste of PDF content - iOS devices

Tags: ios, angular, pdf, asp.net-core, itext

Is there a way I could prevent the user from copying the content of a PDF file on iOS devices?

To detail a bit the background of this query, I have an app that is downloading a PDF and displaying it in the browser. The file is provided by a **.NET Core** web api and the client that it's serving the file is developed in **Angular**.

At the API level I am using **iTextSharp** to encrypt and set permissions for it (just printing permission). This works without any issues on desktop, but not on iOS devices.

If anyone could help me, I would be grateful.

**UPDATE**

.NET Core encryption method

```
public byte[] EncryptPdf(byte[] bytes, string encryptionKey)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new PdfReader(bytes))
                using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
                {
                    stamper.SetEncryption(null, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptionKey),
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
                    stamper.Close();
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Angular snippet for handling the blob

```
downloadFile(data: any) {
    var windowUrl = window.URL || (window as any).webkitURL;
    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data.body, this.getFileName(data));
      return;
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
      const url = windowUrl.createObjectURL(data.body);
      window.location.href = url;
      return;
    }
    saveAs(data.body, this.getFileName(data));
  }
```

Comment: there are print permissions, and copy permissions. Which one did you use?

Comment: here's a post that may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664867/how-to-really-secure-a-pdf-using-itextpdf-preferably

Comment: I only allowed printing. And it works properly on desktop. That solution does not really help iOS devices, that's the problem.

Comment: can you share the code you're using?

Comment: Please don't prevent me from copying the content of your PDF. I am going to OCR it anyway, if you do. (personal opinion)

Comment: I know what you are saying, but what can I say...client request...even though there are other ways to get it