# Use Ghostscript to convert each page of a PDF to images and the output is still PDF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I know that **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC** can select the **Microsoft Print to PDF** printer to output to a PDF file with **Print As Image** checked in the **Advanced Print Setup** dialog. However, I want to use a command to do this. I tried the following command, as a result it failed to convert each page to images (Note the output file is still PDF).

```sh
gs -o 0.999.watermask.compact.screen.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen 0.999.watermask.pdf
```

References

- [7.4 PDF file output](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.54.0/VectorDevices.htm#PDFWRITE)
- [iText 7](https://github.com/itext/itext7) iText 7 for Java represents the next level of SDKs for developers that want to take advantage of the benefits PDF can bring.
- [itext-rups-7.1.14.jar](https://github.com/itext/i7j-rups/releases/tag/7.1.15) iText RUPS iText® 7.1.14 ©2000-2020 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)

Comment: " it should be one of the several png ones" Not so! If you want a PDF file where the contents are images (that is the original input has been rendered to images and then the result 'wrapped up' as a PDF file) then you want one of the pdfimage devices. There are 3 devices, one for 8-bit (grayscale), one for 24 bit (RGB) and one for 32-bit (CMYK). You'll need a reasonably recent version of Ghostscript for that, it's a relatively new feature, new in the March 2018 9.23 release. The pdfwrite device is a 'high level' device and does its best to retain vector objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your -switches include `-dDetectDuplicateImages=true` which under the circumstances should be superfluous and the device selection can be from one of four as pointed out by KenS.

```
gs -o 0.999.watermask.compact.screen.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfimage32 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen 0.999.watermask.pdf
```

[image]

If you want to emulate MS Print As Image PDF on Windows you would find the result in some ways inferior (and often many times bigger). But for comparison it would be,

***NOTE:- "%%printer%%... is for a batch file for a command line use "%printer%...***

```
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dNoCancel -o "%%printer%%Microsoft Print to PDF" -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -f "0.999.watermask.pdf"
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP9IO.png]